# qwt build - qmake build (Qt 5.3)

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qmake, qwt

I want to compile the `qwt` library using qt 5.3. Previously I had older versions of Qt. So, when I call the `Qt 5.3.0 32-bit for Desktop (MSVC 2012 OpenGL)` shell and move to the directory, which contains qwt (`C:\qwt-6.1.0`), then perform `qmake qwt.pro` I get this error:

```
    Cannot read c:/Qt/Qt5.0.2/mkspecs/win32-msvc2010/qmake.conf: The system cannot find
    the path specified. Could not read qmake configuration 
    file c:/Qt/Qt5.0.2/mkspecs/win32-msvc2010/qmake.conf.
    Error processing project file: C:\qwt-6.1.0\qwt.pro
```

Calling:

```
    qmake -set QMAKESPEC "C:\Qt_5.3\5.3\msvc2012_opengl\mkspecs\win32-msvc2012\"
```

Does not help.

PS. Solution is found! I've tried not to do like is in qwt tutorial, simple open *.pro file by Qt Creator. After this just "build" and everything was done. Without console

Comment: Your Qt installation seems broken. It seems you are using the wrong `qmake` Check your `PATH` for which one is picked up first.

Comment: I've checked PATH variable - it is "c:\Qt_5.3\5.3\msvc2012_opengl\mkspecs\win32-msvc2012\;c:\Qt_5.3\5.3\msvc2012_opengl\bin\", seems to be all right

Comment: well, if there is a `qmake` in `c:\Qt_5.3\5.3\msvc2012_op‌​engl\bin\`, then it is broken, because it looks for `mkspec`s in `c:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\...`